# Authorization error when using Google Code and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, authentication, tortoisesvn, google-code

I want to commit my project to https://code.google.com, but TortoiseSVN gives the following error:

> authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://personal-domain-mail-gadget.googlecode.com)

[image: Error]

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: does adding a slash at the end of url helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Google Code servers were not able to successfully authenticate you:

> authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge

Are you sure that you're using the correct user name and password? Remember that it's not the same password as you use for your Gmail account—Google generates/uses a new, separate password for SVN.

You can get (and regenerate) your GoogleCode password here: https://code.google.com/hosting/settings

Comment: Thanks Buddy ! I was using Google Password ! My Mistake at all !

Comment: Will this password remain same forever ? or I need to regenerate to recommit ?

Comment: @Sarang: don't forget to check the answer if it did solve your problem!

Comment: Wow - with all the Google account integration work that's been done over the last few months, one would think that they would have cleaned this problem up! I can use the same password for Gmail, calendar, sites, etc. but not SVN with GoogleCode.

Answer (score 0):

I need to use SVN Password to commit!

I got it from [SVN Password](https://code.google.com/hosting/settings) as per the specification in [Google Code API](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when using mvn release:prepare command on Ubuntu. I double checked password and username, both were correct.

On Ubuntu, this can happen because of some weird interactions with keyrings. You can fix this by editing your ~/.subversion/config file and adding the following line:

password-stores =

It worked fine for me after this change. Note that there is a commented out line with password-stores in the config file. That is not enough, you must actually set it to blank.